# Создание столбца

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица (X) в бд, один из столбцов (Y) которой имеет значение либо 0, либо 1.
Есть "оболочка", в которой создается фильтр. Сам фильтр

```
select 0 as ID, ' ' as NAME from dual
union
select 1 as ID, 'Применяется при поверке/калибровке/аттестации' as NAME from dual
union
select ? as ID, 'Все' as NAME from dual
```

Первая строка отобразит значения таблицы X, в которых Y = 0, это работает.
Вторая строка отображает значения X, в которых Y = 1, это так же работает.
В третьей строке должны будут отображаться значения X, в которых значение столбца Y = и 0 и 1, т.е. все значения. Непонятный момент отразил знаком вопроса. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, возможность реализации именно подобным изуверским способом.

Comment: Вместо знака вопроса вписал NULL и заработало) прошу прощения за вопрос.

Comment: У вас что-то с дизайном не так. Если в третьей строчке null, то "Не орределено", а не "Всё"

Comment: Мне кажется, что третья строка вообще не нужна, т.к. первые две уже включают оба варианта. :-)